# Como añado las operaciones a mi calculadora

Tags: java, eventos, jpanel, calculo

estoy creando una calculadora en Java, usando ventanas y paneles en Netbeans.
La interfaz gráfica de la calculadora ya la tengo hecha, pero no sé cómo hacer que sea funcional, es decir, que realice las operaciones.
Os dejo el código por aquí por si alguien pudiera echarme un cable.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Calculadora;

//Zona de imports
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */
public class calculadoraFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creamos la ventana para la calculadora
        Frame ventana = new Frame("Calculadora JM");
        ventana.setSize(600, 500);
        ventana.setVisible(true);

        Panel panelcentro = new Panel();
        Panel panelDerecha = new Panel();
        Panel panelIzquierda = new Panel();
        Panel panelAbajo = new Panel();

        //Lineas, columnas, horizontal y vertical
        GridLayout numeros = new GridLayout(4, 3, 4, 4);
        GridLayout gridDerecha = new GridLayout(4, 1, 4, 4);
        GridLayout gridIzquierda = new GridLayout(4, 1, 4, 4);
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

        panelcentro.setLayout(numeros);
        panelDerecha.setLayout(gridDerecha);
        panelIzquierda.setLayout(gridIzquierda);
        panelAbajo.setLayout(cardLayout);

        Dimension dim = new Dimension(120, 0);
        panelDerecha.setPreferredSize(dim);
        panelIzquierda.setPreferredSize(dim);

        BorderLayout miBorderLayout = new BorderLayout(5, 0);
        ventana.setLayout(miBorderLayout);

        TextField cajaTexto = new TextField("");

        ventana.add(cajaTexto, "North");
        ventana.add(panelcentro, "Center");
        ventana.add(panelDerecha, "East");
        ventana.add(panelIzquierda, "West");
        ventana.add(panelAbajo, "South");

        Button boton1 = new Button("1");
        Button boton2 = new Button("2");
        Button boton3 = new Button("3");
        Button boton4 = new Button("4");
        Button boton5 = new Button("5");
        Button boton6 = new Button("6");
        Button boton7 = new Button("7");
        Button boton8 = new Button("8");
        Button boton9 = new Button("9");
        Button botonc = new Button("c");
        Button boton0 = new Button("0");
        Button botonigual = new Button("=");

        panelcentro.add(boton1);
        panelcentro.add(boton2);
        panelcentro.add(boton3);
        panelcentro.add(boton4);
        panelcentro.add(boton5);
        panelcentro.add(boton6);
        panelcentro.add(boton7);
        panelcentro.add(boton8);
        panelcentro.add(boton9);
        panelcentro.add(botonc);
        panelcentro.add(boton0);
        panelcentro.add(botonigual);

        Button botonsumar = new Button("+");
        Button botonrestar = new Button("-");
        Button botonmultiplicar = new Button("*");
        Button botondividir = new Button("/");

        panelDerecha.add(botonsumar);
        panelDerecha.add(botonrestar);
        panelDerecha.add(botonmultiplicar);
        panelDerecha.add(botondividir);

        Button botonraiz = new Button("√");
        Button botonelevar = new Button("xº");
        Button botonabrirparentesis = new Button("(");
        Button botoncerrarparentesis = new Button(")");

        botonraiz.setVisible(false);
        botonelevar.setVisible(false);
        botonabrirparentesis.setVisible(false);
        botoncerrarparentesis.setVisible(false);

        panelIzquierda.add(botonraiz);
        panelIzquierda.add(botonelevar);
        panelIzquierda.add(botonabrirparentesis);
        panelIzquierda.add(botoncerrarparentesis);

        Button botonactivarDerecha = new Button("Activar Parte Derecha");
        Button botonactivarIzquierda = new Button("Activar Parte Izquierda");
        panelAbajo.add(botonactivarIzquierda);
        panelAbajo.add(botonactivarDerecha);

        ventana.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                ventana.dispose();
            }
        });

        //Creamos la barra de menus
        MenuBar barrita = new MenuBar();
        //Creamos la primera pestaña del menu
        Menu pest1 = new Menu("Calculadora");

        //Creamos los diferentes items para esa pestaña
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("suma");
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("resta");
        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("multiplicación");
        MenuItem item13 = new MenuItem("division");

        //Añadimos los items a la pestaña
        pest1.add(item13);
        pest1.add(item1);
        pest1.add(item2);
        pest1.add(item3);

        //Repetimos el proceso con la segunda pestaña
        Menu pest2 = new Menu("Guardar como");
        MenuItem item4 = new MenuItem(".txt");
        MenuItem item5 = new MenuItem(".java");
        pest2.add(item4);
        pest2.add(item5);
        pest1.add(pest2);

        Menu pest3 = new Menu("Creditos");
        Menu menu5 = new Menu("Autor");
        MenuItem item7 = new MenuItem("Jorge Moya");
        pest3.add(menu5);
        menu5.add(item7);
        Menu pest4 = new Menu("Política de privacidad");
        pest3.add(pest4);

        //aádir las pestañas al menu
        barrita.add(pest1);
        barrita.add(pest3);
        barrita.add(pest4);

        //Añadir la barra a la ventana
        ventana.setMenuBar(barrita);
        
        //ActionListeners para que los numeros se escriban en la caja de texto
        boton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "1");
            }

        });

        boton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "2");
            }

        });

        boton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "3");
            }

        });

        boton4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "4");
            }

        });
        boton5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "5");
            }

        });
        boton6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "6");
            }

        });
        boton7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "7");
            }

        });
        boton8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "8");
            }

        });
        boton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "9");
            }

        });
        botonc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText("");
            }

        });
        boton0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "0");
            }

        });
        botonigual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "=");
            }

        });
        botonsumar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "+");
            }

        });

        botonrestar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "-");
            }

        });

        botonmultiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "*");
            }

        });
        botondividir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "/");
            }

        });

        botonraiz.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "√");
            }

        });
        botonelevar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "º");
            }

        });
        botonabrirparentesis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "(");
            }

        });
        botoncerrarparentesis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + ")");
            }

        });

        botonactivarDerecha.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                botonraiz.setVisible(false);
                botonelevar.setVisible(false);
                botonabrirparentesis.setVisible(false);
                botoncerrarparentesis.setVisible(false);

                botonsumar.setVisible(true);
                botonrestar.setVisible(true);
                botonmultiplicar.setVisible(true);
                botondividir.setVisible(true);

                cardLayout.next(panelAbajo);
            }
        });

        botonactivarIzquierda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                botonraiz.setVisible(true);
                botonelevar.setVisible(true);
                botonabrirparentesis.setVisible(true);
                botoncerrarparentesis.setVisible(true);

                botonsumar.setVisible(false);
                botonrestar.setVisible(false);
                botonmultiplicar.setVisible(false);
                botondividir.setVisible(false);

                cardLayout.next(panelAbajo);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Implementar un evaluador de expresiones matemáticas no es una tarea trivial. Aquí tienes una lista de librerías que puedes usar para obtener un resultado a partir de una expresión matemática https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/method-for-evaluating-math-expressions-in-java Si la expresión es más o menos sencilla, podrías usar la clase javax.script.ScriptEngine

Answer (score 1):

a ver si te voy dando una idea de como lo veo

primero declaras las variables de clase, yo iré a lo sencillo operando con int, pero lo lógico sería que para el resultado fuera con double o float:

```
static String valor1 = "";
static String valor2 = "";
static int resultado = 0;
static String operacion = "";
```

luego en los botones de las operaciones matemáticas, en éste caso en el botón "+":

```
botonsumar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //evalúas que la variable valor1 no tenga datos, si los tiene, quizás sea porque tanto la variable como la operación ya esté almacenada, y en lugar de apretar el signo igual, por error han vuelto a presionar en otra operación, por lo que habría que arrojar un error
            if (valor1 == ""){
                //asignamos el valor de la caja de texto a la variable valor1
                valor1 = cajaTexto.getText();
                //limpiamos la caja de texto de números
                cajaTexto.setText("");
                //escribimos la operación elegida
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "+");
            } 
        }
    });
```

luego en el botón del número 9, te pongo éste como ejemplo, habría que hacer lo mismo en los demás:

```
boton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //asignamos el valor de la caja de texto al string ope
            String ope = cajaTexto.getText();
            //evaluamos que ese string sea una operación matemática, ésto signoficaría que se han limpiado anteriormente los números y éstos han ido a parar a la variable valor1
            if ((ope.equals("+")) || (ope.equals("-")) || (ope.equals("*")) || (ope.equals("/"))){
                //si lo es, en la variable operacion almacenamos el símbolo elegido por el usuario que tenemos acutalmente en la caja de texto
                operacion = cajaTexto.getText();
                //limpiamos la caja de texto
                cajaTexto.setText("");
                //imprimimos el número, en éste caso el 9
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "9");
            }
            else{
                //si no hay operacion, lo seguimos imprimiendo con normalidad
                ((TextField) ventana.getComponentAt(cajaTexto.getLocation())).setText(cajaTexto.getText() + "9");
            }
            
        }

    });
```

Finalmente en el botón "=";

```
});
    botonigual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //evaluamos que las dos variables de valor1 y operación tengan dato
            if ((valor1 != "") && (operacion != "")){
                //almacenamos en valor2 lo contenido en la caja de texto
                valor2 = cajaTexto.getText();
                //limpiamos la caja de texto
                cajaTexto.setText("");
                //convertimos en números los valores1 y 2
                int v1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
                int v2 = Integer.parseInt(valor2);
                //realizamos la operación
                resultado = v1 + v2;
                //convertimos el resultado en string
                String resu = String.valueOf(resultado);
                //lo mostramos en la caja de texto
                cajaTexto.setText(String.valueOf(resu));
            }
        }
    });
```

Es una idea, te tecaría depurar mucho el programa añadiendo más condicionales y salidas en caso de interrupciones, pero te puede servir de guía